# How delete elements from map

Tags: c++, containers

I want to delete some map elements satisfying a condition. I did find a solution but I did not know how use it.

I have:

```
std::map<char,int> first;
first['a']=10;
first['b']=60;
first['c']=50;
first['d']=70;
```

the solution given is :

```
namespace stuff {
    template< typename ContainerT, typename PredicateT >
    void erase_if( ContainerT& items, const PredicateT& predicate ) {
        for( auto it = items.begin(); it != items.end(); ) {
            if( predicate(*it) ) it = items.erase(it);
            else ++it;
        }
    };
}
```

What I need is how to adopt this function to delete elements having number <= 50:

```
using stuff::erase_if;
int test_value = 50;  // or use whatever appropriate type and value
erase_if(container, [&test_value]( item_type& item ) {
    return item.property <= test_value;  // or whatever appropriate test
});
```

Comment: Why does your lambda use `item_type& item` when your map holds a `char`?

Comment: If you just want to delete the first two elements, then why do you even need that function? What's wrong with calling `erase` twice?

Comment: Why didn't try to use [map::erase](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/erase/)

Comment: @BorislavKostov Prefer [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/) to that site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue here is with your lambda in

```
erase_if(container, [&test_value]( item_type& item ) {
    return item.property <= test_value;  // or whatever appropriate test
});
```

You have `item_type& item` and `item.property` which is not what you want.  When you dereference a map iterator you get a `std::pair<const key_type, T>` and that is what the lambda needs to take.  We could use

```
erase_if(container, [&test_value]( const std::map<char,int>::value_type& item ) {
    return item.second <= test_value;
});
```

But this means if we change the map to use some other key we need to change the type of `item`.  To avoid that we can use a generic lambda using `auto` like

```
erase_if(container, [&test_value]( const auto& item ) {
    return item.second <= test_value;
});
```

Comment: yup that what I need but I think I need to modify the parameters definition of the function erase_if since it uses std::pair

Comment: @Blood-HaZaRd Oops.  Forgot about that the iterator returns a value key pair.  Let me fix that.

Answer (score 4):

Why not use [`std::map::erase`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/erase)? As in

```
first.erase(first.begin());
```

That will remove the "first" item from the map.

If you want to remove a specific key, then it's just the same:

```
first.erase('a');
```

Comment: sorry I modifed the problem so I want delete 1st and third

Comment: @Blood-HaZaRd And with "third" do you mean a specific key (like `'c'`)? Or the third from `begin()`?

Comment: @BorislavKostov Unfortunately map iterators are not random-access iterators, so you can't use binary `+`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude : I meant third becaue in this exmaple I have the value 50 as third element so I want to delete all eleme,nts having values less than 50. in other way I may delete the 4th not the 3rd in some other cases

Comment: remove_if is sot usable with assosiative containers

Comment: @Blood-HaZaRd If I understand you correctly, you want to know what `item_type` should be? And what `item.property` really is? Then I suggest you study what each "element" of a [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) is. That should make it very clear. Hint: It's a *pair* of values... Check out `std::map::value_type`.